# Finding a curve through a zero-cycle and a dense subset

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Is it true that for any smooth irreducible projective $k$-variety $X$ and a dense open set $U\subset X$, for any zero-cycle on $X$ one can find an irreducible curve containing its support and meeting $U$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *yes* if $X$ is geometrically irreducible (namely, irreducible over every field extension of $k$).

Just take a finite set of points $F$ consisting of the support of your zero-cycle together with any point of $U$, and then apply the following Bertini-type result, see Theorem 1.8 and Corollary 1.9 in

F. Charles, B. Poonen [*Bertini irreducibility theorems over finite fields*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-2014-00820-1), J. Am. Math. Soc. **29**, No. 1, 81-94 (2016); erratum ibid. **32**, No. 2, 605-607 (2019). [ZBL1327.14233](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1327.14233).

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a geometrically irreducible variety of dimension $m \geq 2$ over a field $k$. Let $F\subset X$ be a finite set of points. Then for all $1 \leq y \leq m$ there exists a $y$-dimensional, geometrically irreducible subvariety $Y \subset X$ containing $F$.

Comment: but unless you are over an algebraically closed field, you need to be geometrically irreducible for this to hold, right? Is there a counterexample for irreducible, not geometrically irreducible smooth projective variety?

Comment: Well, this actually I do not know. I also had in mind the algebraically closed field case.